# How to calculate effective equipment impairment value Ie-eff?

Tags: voip, rtp, qos

I am trying to find the MOS score for calls, and now stuck at Ie-eff calculation.
From ITU-T g 113 doc i got the below table data, but i couldn't get the Ie-eff values as in below table by the following calculation.

Ie-eff=Ie+(95-Ie).Ppl/((ppl/BurstR)+Bpl)

I tried for Codec G711 with values Ie=0,bpl=4.8,Ppl=1.5(table data) and BurstR=5.91(table data)

[image]

Can anyone please suggest a solution.